# How to call a method of one class from another class - android

Tags: java, android

I already searched on this but couldnt find the answer as I dont know in which side I am doing wrong. Whenever I class this method I got the error from where I am calling.

I am calling from this method in checkpass.java class

```
 private void checking() {
    okbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
            testClass.testing();

        }
    });
}
```

I am calling this method which is located in another class

```
public void testing(){
    Toast.makeText(TestClass.this, "Testing class", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:287)
at com.futureappspk.WeTextFree.TestClass.testing(TestClass.java:18)
at com.futureappspk.WeTextFree.CheckPass$1.onClick(CheckPass.java:43)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4746)
```

Comment: You didn't include your error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**testClass** is not `Activity` so you failed here `TestClass.this`.

Better to pass **context** to `testing(Context mContext){` and used it

```
public void testing(Context mContext){
Toast.makeText(mContext, "Testing class", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and call from anywhere

```
testClass.testing(yourActivity.this);
```

Comment: its very helpful and actually its working ,i ignored a big error , thnks alot u made my day

Comment: @M D will  you help me if i extended my question ?

Comment: @ArslanAliAwan Please asked another question. Damn help you.

Comment: @M D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572179/how-to-call-one-method-from-another-class-in-android?noredirect=1#comment58832539_35572179 please come on this

Comment: @M D basically am doing this task which i mentioned u in above link, help me man if it is easy4 u . thnks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the `Context` to be able to `Toast`, you would want to pass your `Context` to this other class, either when you are calling testing, or when you are initializing the `Testing()` object.
Your context, if in an activity can be obtained by calling `getApplicationContext()`. Simply passing `[ACTIVITY_NAME].this` would also work.

** passing to function ** [I find this preferable]

`otherActivityObject.testing(thisActivity.this);`

** at init **

`OtherActivity otherActivityObject = new OtherActivity(thisActivity.this);
otherActivityObject.testing();`

Comment: @ArslanAliAwan sure :)