# How to call one method from another class in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When ever im calling `fromcheckpass(mcontext)` im getting nullpointerexception. Where imdoing wrong. Help me out!

From `onClick()` i'm calling `fromcheckpass(mcontext)`.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    InboxActivity inboxActivity = new InboxActivity();
    inboxActivity.fromcheckpass(CheckPass.this);
}
```

How can I call `fromcheckpass(mcontext)` method ?

```
public void fromcheckpass(Context mcontext) {
    Toast.makeText(mcontext, "WEL COME", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
    String DbInsert = Utils.getPreferences("DbInsert", this);

    if (!DbInsert.equalsIgnoreCase("Inserted")) {
        SaveDataInDB();
    }

    MessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvInbox);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new    ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0154A4")));
    bar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    bar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>WeText </font>"));
    bar.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_top);

    Utils.getOverflowMenu(this);

    attachListeners();

    dataList = Utils.getLatestMessageOfAllContacts(InboxActivity.this);

    if (dataList.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO MESSAGES", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        iAdapter = new Adapter(InboxActivity.this, dataList);
        MessageListView.setAdapter(iAdapter);
    }
}
```

Whenever I call fromCheckpass(mcontex) method the app crashes. Here is my logcat:

```
Process: com.futureappspk.WeTextFree, PID: 29065
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:186)
        at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
        at com.futureappspk.WeTextFree.Utils.getPreferences(Utils.java:432)
        at com.futureappspk.WeTextFree.InboxActivity.fromcheckpass(InboxActivity.java:130)
        at com.futureappspk.WeTextFree.CheckPass$1.onClick(CheckPass.java:40)
```

Here is my util class method which is calling `fromcheckpass(mcontext)`

```
public static String getPreferences(String key, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String userName = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "UserName");
    return userName;
}
```

Comment: show your logcat...what is the error..

Comment: @BajiraoShinde i posted my logcat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Xoce NullpointerException might be the exception here, but your link won't help.
Arslan Ali Awan should not instantiate a Activity directly. It won't have a Context.

Comment: if the cause of the error is a NPE, then the question is duplicated.#

Comment: Can you show your Utils class ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna i posted my utils class method

Comment: @ArslanAliAwan hi, have you solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try This 
I think your CheckPass is not your Activity.
Hence pass Context correctly like
    getActivity() or getApplicationContext();
in onClick Method
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

To inform you the error is at this line

```
String DbInsert = Utils.getPreferences("DbInsert", this);
```

**Possible reasons**

You have to use `getSharedPreferences` with the instance of `Context` class like

```
ctx.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF",0);
```

You have not shown your `Utils` class but as I guess `getPreferences` method is a static method of the class and you are calling it directly without initializing any `Context` of application. So I suggest you to initialize the `Context` in the `Constructor` of your `Utils` class and use the `getSharedPreferences` method only with the instance of `Utils` class.

**UPDATE**

Try not to make it static, do something like this

```
public class Utils {
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences; 

public Utils (Context context) {
   this.sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);    
}
public String getPreferences(String key) {
   sharedPreferences.getString(key, "UserName");
    return userName;
  }
}
```